# Average Pooling layer in Deep Learning and gradient artifacts

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network, medical-imaging

I know that in Convolution layers the kernel size needs to be a multiplication of stride or else it will produce artefacts in gradient calculations like the checkerboard problem.
Now does it also work like that in Pooling layers? I read somewhere that max pooling can also cause problems like that. Take this line in the discriminator for example:

```
  self.downsample = nn.AvgPool2d(3, stride=2, padding=1, count_include_pad=False)
```

I have a model (MUNIT) with it, and this is the image it produced:

[image]

It looks like the checkerboard problem, or at least a gradient problem but I checked my Convolution layers and didn't found the error described above. They all are of size 4 with stride 2 or an uneven size with stride of 1.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't look like a checkerboard artifact honestly. Also I don't think discriminator would be the problem, it's usually about image restoration (generator or decoder).

Took a quick look at the MUNIT and what they use in `Decoder` is `torch.nn.Upsample` with nearest neighbor upsampling (exact code line [here](https://github.com/NVlabs/MUNIT/blob/master/networks.py#L232)).

You may try to use `torch.nn.Conv2d` followed by [`torch.nn.PixelShuffle`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.PixelShuffle.html), something like this:

```
import torch

in_channels = 32
upscale_factor = 2
out_channels = 16

upsampling = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Conv2d(
        in_channels,
        out_channels * upscale_factor * upscale_factor,
        kernel_size=3,
        padding=1,
    ),
    torch.nn.PixelShuffle(upscale_factor),
)

image = torch.randn(1, 32, 16, 16)

upsampling(image).shape  # [1, 16, 32, 32]
```

This allows neural network to learn how to upsample the image instead of merely using `torch.nn.Upsample` which the network has no control over (and using below trick it should also be free of checkerboard artifacts).

Additionally, ICNR initialization for `Conv2d` should also help (possible implementation [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/5429/commits/4fea7cb83366a95b2eb9f64a9161b35d0e412f66) or [here](https://github.com/szymonmaszke/torchlayers/blob/master/torchlayers/upsample.py#L116)). This init scheme initializes weights to act similar to nearest neighbor upsampling at the beginning (research paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.02937.pdf)).